# WCF Visual Studio 2010 Deployment Issue

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF web service that works locally.  I can consume it from my web project with no problem. Now I want to deploy it to IIS 7. Any instructions on how to move this service to IIS? 
I tried to publish to a new site I created for the service valled WCFService but I got an error which says **"The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed"**

Any suggestions on deploying this to IIS properly? What are the necessary steps to get this local copy working remotely ?Thanks

Comment: You indicate you are trying to publish to a remote server. Is this remote server using IIS Web Deploy (http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I followed th Endpoint.tv example so I created a wcf library. This is why I do not have an svc file. Is it as simple as manually creating an svc file for the library?